# Previewing react-native views using ReactJS in a web browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

(Disclaimer: I'd have asked this question in a forum but the `react-native` website encourages us to ask it on SO.)

Is there a known tool to visually preview xml layouts in a browser? I'm developping a scaffolding tool to generate basic templates so I can prepare applications for customers quicker, and I'd like it to be a web app. Since the layout is very similar between react-native and `reactJS`, I'd think the effort to show a `react-native` layout as a `reactJS` layout is minimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A framework for building web apps with React Native compatible API

https://github.com/taobaofed/react-web

Comment: Crazy. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and to avoid asking another small question: do you happen to know if there is an existing "scaffolding" tool for react-native? Ex. You shoot a model, it generates a view-model binding. Throwing a list of items into it would generate a listview with enough cells for all properties, for example.

Comment: don't really know what you want,an IDE stuff?maybe check this out. https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools